# How to achieve vector input/output with different operations using anonymous functions?

Tags: matlab, function, anonymous-function

Suppose I want to create an anonymous function that does the following

```
f: [a, b] -> [a^2, b/2]
```

Since the operation is different on `a` and `b` I haven't been able to figure out how. Is this at all possible in matlab? My function will have the constraints `R^2 -> R^2`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of the specific constraints, it would have to be something like this:

```
f = @(x) [x(1)^2, x(2)/2];
```

You can't explicitly define outputs in an anonymous function any other way.

Comment: Thanks, this does exactly what I want (how come I didnt think of this? :D)

Answer (score 4):

Though you already accepted [**PQL's answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39071754/2605073) your question actually reads like you're looking for this solution using [**`deal`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deal.html):

```
f = @(x,y) deal( x^2, y/2 );

[u,v] = f(2,2)
```

returning:

```
u =
     4
v =
     1
```

Comment: thanks for the inspiration. I knew I was looking for something regarding cell arrays

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the matlab help for anonymous functions looking at section [functions with multiple inputs or outputs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com#f4-70159), I would think that you would be able to do something like the code below

**Second edit**  Turns out if you use deal (as given by [thewaywewalk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2605073/thewaywewalk))  or if you dereference the anonymous function you can get the same thing.

```
crazyfunction=@(a,b) {(a^2),(b/2)};
[x y]=crazyfunction(a,b);
```

Quick and dirty test shows that this will give no syntax errors

```
>> f = @(x,y)  {x^2, y/2};
>> f(2,2)

ans = 

    [4]    [1]
```

**EDIT** Fired up matlab to see my original answer would actually work, doesn't look like it (see second edit you need to use {}).

You would either daisy chain two anonymous functions together in such a way that a and b are part of anonymous function c or use a struct of anonymous functions effectively  as shown below

```
crazyfunction={@(a) (a^2); @(b) (b/2);}
[crazyfunction{1](7) crazyfunction{2}(9)]
ans = 
    49.0000     4.5
```